# why is my WCF server so slow

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, task, wcf-binding

I have created a WCF server and a WCF client to consume the service.
The purpose of the server is to add 2 numbers being passed in and wait X milliseconds before returning the sum.

The client creates Y tasks and starts them. Each task is a request for the server to add numbers and wait the X milliseconds.

When x = 0 and y = 1000 it takes an average of 6.2 Seconds to complete all tasks.
When X = 0 and Y = 10000 it takes an average of 61 Seconds to complete all tasks.

Why is it so slow or maybe this is normal?

thanks
Damo

**Client C# methods**

```
private void radButtonTaskWithStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var dateTime1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
                radProgressBarStatus.Maximum = int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text);
                radProgressBarStatus.Value1 = 0;

                Random rnd = new Random();


                Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text)];

                for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text); i++)
                {
                    int x = i;
                    tasks[i] = new Task<int>(() =>
                    {    

                        int FirstRandomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 20);
                        int SecondRandomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 20);


                        int result = TaskRequestWithResult(FirstRandomNumber, SecondRandomNumber, int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodDelay.Text), x);    

                        return result;
                    });
                }

                var continuation = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
                            tasks,
                            (antecedents) =>
                            {
                                var dateTime2 = DateTime.UtcNow;
                                var diffInSeconds = (dateTime2 - dateTime1).TotalSeconds;
                                this.radListView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.radListView1.Items.Add((dateTime2 - dateTime1).TotalSeconds)));
                                //MessageBox.Show(diffInSeconds.ToString());


                                int total = 0;
                                for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text); i++)
                                    total = total + tasks[i].Result;
                                Debug.Print("Finished - Sum of all results is: " + total);
                                //RadMessageBox.Show("Finished - Sum of all results is: " + total);                     
                            });


                for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text); i++)
                {
                    tasks[i].Start();
                  //  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); // Wait
                }

                TaskProgress(tasks, count => Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => radProgressBarStatus.Value1 = count)));

                // Use next line if you want to block the main thread until all the tasks are complete
                //continuation.Wait();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

            }
        }

        public static void TaskProgress(IEnumerable<Task> tasks, Action<int> callback)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var task in tasks)
                task.ContinueWith(t => callback(Interlocked.Increment(ref count)));
        }

        private int TaskRequestWithResult(int number1, int number2, int delay, int count)
        {

            try
            {

                ServiceReference1.WCFJobsLibraryClient Client = new ServiceReference1.WCFJobsLibraryClient();
                Client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(radTextBoxbaseAddress.Text);
                WCFClient.ServiceReference1.ReturnClass AddNumbers_Result;

                AddNumbers_Result = Client.AddNumbers(number1, number2, delay);


                if (AddNumbers_Result.ErrorCode < 0)
                {
                    // If exception happens, it will be returned here
                    MessageBox.Show(AddNumbers_Result.ErrorCode.ToString() + " " + AddNumbers_Result.ErrorMessage + " " + AddNumbers_Result.ExMessage);
                }

                else
                {
                    Debug.Print("Task Executing now: " + count.ToString());                   

                }

                return AddNumbers_Result.Result;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                return -1;

            }
        }


    }
```

**Client App.config**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFService/WCFJobsLibrary/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpoint"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IWCFJobsLibrary" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Server C# methods**

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class WCFJobsLibrary : IWCFJobsLibrary
{

    public ReturnClass AddNumbers(int FirstNumber, int SecondNumber, int Delay) //Add two numbers and wait a predefined interval
    {
        Logging.Write_To_Log_File("Entry", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "", "", "", 1);
        ReturnClass myReturnClass = new ReturnClass(-1, null, null, 0);
        try
        {             

            myReturnClass.ErrorCode = 1;

            myReturnClass.Result = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Delay); // Wait
            Logging.Write_To_Log_File("Exit", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "", "", "", 1);
            return myReturnClass;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.Write_To_Log_File("Error", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "", "", ex.ToString(), 2);
            myReturnClass.ErrorCode = -1;
            myReturnClass.ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
            return myReturnClass;
        }

    }

//Add two numbers and wait defined interval
[OperationContract]
ReturnClass AddNumbers(int FirstNumber, int SecondNumber, int Delay);
```

**Server App.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="WCFService.WCFJobsLibrary" behaviorConfiguration="Throttled" >
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
        name="BasicHttpEndpoint" contract="WCFService.IWCFJobsLibrary">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFService/WCFJobsLibrary/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Throttled">
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100000" maxConcurrentInstances="100000" maxConcurrentSessions="100000" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: your performance based on time is fine, it is linear...

Comment: I cannot help but notice that your 2 values for Y are different by a factor of 10 and that your difference in response times as also by a factor of 10.  Are you quite sure that Y is not being used in your wait calculation ?

Comment: Its the WCF... It performance slow so you're forced to hire consultants to fix it for you :D

Comment: You are sleeping on the server side!  Why would you *not* expect it to be slow?

Comment: my sleep value is x and x = 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not WCF, but your architecture what is slowing you down.

For example, you are creating 1k tasks which will try to take threads from ThreadPool, every task completes only when it gets response from your WCF service (it's calling your WCF service synchronously, on per-task basis).

Now, you might think that you will start 1k or 10k jobs at once, but in reality, .NET's threadpool will start with small amount of threads, fe. 4 and increase their number over time when needed, this can take some time.

You can quickly check if this is the bottleneck by increasing *minimum* number of threads that should be allocated by threadpool:

```
int min, io;
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out min, out io);
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, io);
```

This is just how to circumvent your problem, not solve it, your architecture should be different, spread your work between 2-4 tasks, not 10k!

Also, it seems that you are creating a new client for each of your request, basically, you are doing a lot of plumbing work, allocate a lot of resources (#task != #threads, but those are correlated still), for a very simple task, so you are not really measuring WCF work, but your work.

Comment: how can i "spread your work between 2-4 tasks, not 10k" - and if i did that would it perform faster?

Comment: You could create N tasks and in each task, in normal for loop, you would generate x / N requests, so in total you would have x / N * N = x requests as you wanted to, but you would create only N clients and  allocate no more than N threads for this task. This however would not work if your server would block for long, as you would have only N tasks scheduled the job at once. The best way to fix it is use asynchronous WCF servics, so you could just schedule x requests from 1 thread without waiting for them to finish and use threadpool threads only to receive results.

Comment: +1 :) for the great ans